# Cufon works in Webkit, not in Firefox, why would this happen?

Tags: jquery, firefox, fonts, cufon

http://scohoe.com/dev/

The site looks like it should on webkit browsers(chrome/safari) but for some reason cufon isn't replacing the font in Firefox, and I haven't had a chance to test IE yet so it may be happening there too.

I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong, does anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at your includes. You are mixing relative urls (no `/` prefix) with absolute urls. You also have an invalid url which starts with `//` (two slashes). Start by fixing these and see if the issue persists.

Comment: There is no problem with mixing relative URL with absolute URL while the URL is correct. Also, a URL starting with two slashes (`//`) is not invalid, it's called "protocol-relative URL". http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/